# jquery .append() sometimes fail

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to add elements to a dynamic blank list.

I go through a loop like this in the script that's called from a dynamically created event handler.
like this:

```
for (var o in dataArr) {
   var coreArr = dataArr[o],
       insStr = "";
   for (var op in coreArr) {
      insStr += showInsData(op);
   }
   $("#" + o).append(insStr);
}
```

or

```
for (var o in dataArr) {
   var coreArr = dataArr[o];
   for (var op in coreArr) {
       var insStr = showInsData(op);
       $("#" + o).append(insStr);
   } 
}
```

two methods sometimes work and add the element.But sometimes two methods don't load the element.
I had been tested that `insStr` and `"#" + o` both hava value. But .append() is sometimes not working.

I really can't fix this issue. If anyone has a better solution, please let me know.
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Don't write code like this.

```
var coreArr = dataArr[o],
       insStr = "";
```

Then you loop over coreArr[0], that's an array?

Tagging this as jquery is probably not the right problem. I think it might have to do with the data before it? Post more of the code and keep debugging.

Comment: `coreArr` is array .    `var coreArr = dataArr[o],insStr = "";` this code is not problem .When don't load the element , `insStr` and `"#" + o` both have value .

Answer (score 0):

try this

> `` $(`# ${o}`).append(insStr); ``

instead of

> `$("#" + o).append(insStr);`

you can use tilde sign (`) for concatenation

Comment: I have tried it, but sometimes there will still be unsuccessful situations